# How to show gnome-terminal menubar?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I accidentally unchecked *View -> Show Menubar* which hides the menubar for gnome-terminal,  and there doesn't appear to be a keyboard shortcut to show the menubar again.

[image]

How can I make gnome-terminal show the menubar again?

Comment: I wonder what the  purpose of hiding that menubar in first place is.

Comment: @neverMind9 Having a cleaner interface; why would you bloat your screen with stuff you never use?

Comment: @Destroyer I see. But that _stuff_ does not bother me personally.

Comment: it is amazing solution

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Right click anywhere inside the terminal, and you'll get a similar pop up menu that lets you reenable it.

[image]

---

If you're running an application that controls the terminal via the Ncurses library (which are most TUI applications, like **vi**), you need **Shift + Right-Click**, or to exit or suspend the application first.  (I.e. `^Z` (control-Z) to suspend, then right click to get this menu, and select **Show MenuBar**, then finally enter `%` and `↵ Enter` to resume.)

Comment: and... once the menu appears, go into Edit->Profile Preferences->General and click "Show menubar by default in new windows".  THis applies to at least GNOME Terminal 2.31.3

Comment: it does not work in tmux. I need to open new tab/window and then context menu works.

Comment: Mine was already checked. Unchecked and checked and still, no menu is shown.

Answer (score 25):

You can also make it via terminal command line:

```
gnome-terminal  --show-menubar
```

If you read the `man gnome-terminal` you can find this:

```
  --show-menubar
                 Turn  on  the menu bar for the last-specified window; applies
                 to only one window; can be specified once for each window you
                 create from the command line.
```

Comment: Opens a new terminal window, rather than fixing anything. :-(

Answer (score 2):

To add to [Jorge Castro's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/19917/1320683) (I can't comment on answers yet), holding shift while right clicking gives you (or me at least) that same context menu when running tmux or vi.

Comment: This is the way to go if you are using a terminal multiplexer like `tmux`.