# What does the menubar do in ubuntu terminal?

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal

If I right click on a terminal in ubuntu, there is this "Show Menu Bar" option.
If it is checked or not it doesn't make any difference anywhere. So what does it do ?

Kinda related question: [How to show gnome-terminal menubar?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19916/how-to-show-gnome-terminal-menubar)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default terminal being used in Ubuntu is actually intended for Gnome environment, where you can see top Menubars of applications you are running constantly . However, Unity - the default environment in Ubuntu,  always auto hides Menubars.Thus the "Show Menu Bar" option is useful when in Gnome environment, and as you stated doesn't make any difference in Unity.